# Is the existence of the supremum and the existence of the infimum equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ is ordered set.

1. for every $A \subset X$, if $A$ has upper bound, $A$ has supremum
2. for every $A\subset X$, if $A$ has lower bound, $A$ has infimum

Are these two propositions equal?

Comment: Is ordered set partially ordered set?

Answer (score 0):

You may know how to prove the infimum of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that has a lower bound exists has an infimum, from the completeness axiom (which states every subset which has an upper bound has a supremum.) We can see that the same argument works for any partially ordered sets.

I will sketch the proof of 2 from 1. The remaining direction is analogous. Let $(P,\le)$ be a partially ordered set, and $X\subseteq P$ be a subset that has a lower bound. Let $L$ be the set of all lower bounds of $X$. We can see that $L$ has an upper bound: in fact, any element of $X$ is an upper bound of $L$.

By the assumption, $L$ has the supremum, say it $l$. You can see that if $m$ is a lower bound of $X$, then $m\le l$. We claim that $l$ is a lower bound of $X$, so $l$ is actually the infimum of $X$.

Assume that $l$ is not the lower bound of $X$. Then there is $a\in X$ such that $l\nleq a$. For any $m\in L$, $m\le a$. However, $l=\sup L$ shows $l\le a$, a contradiction.